# How can I code a template in a file instead of in a script?

Tags: angularjs

I have been using this code:

```
modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceController'
            });
```

and

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Notification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ er.msg }}
    </div>
    <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>-->
</script>
```

How can I recode this inside a file rather than inside a .  Also is there a big disadvantage in doing that. The only thing I can think of is it will take time to get the first copy of the template.  But then I assume it would be served from cache.

Comment: did you try just putting it in a file?  Without the enclosing <script> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same as creating any normal HTML file.

For e.g., suppose you have a HTML file containing the template and you have saved it in a folder named partials in your web app root.

The HTML content will be the same, except the script tag

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Notification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ er.msg }}
    </div>
    <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>-->
```

You then just need to pass the relative URL to your template location like this :

```
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'partials/yourtemplate.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceController'
    });
```

This is valid with assumption that your template is accessible at a location **http://localhost:port//YourApp/partials/yourtemplate.html**

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at templateCache: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

This basically concatenates the templates into a single file that can then be minified, merged and served, preventing the download of multiple `.html` view files.

Answer (score 1):

Only disadvantage is that extra network call to load another html file. Try putting your html contents in a file and save it as `myModalContent.html`.

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Notification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ er.msg }}
    </div>
    <!--<div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>-->
```